# Best way to have development and deployment branches with disjoint sets of files where one generates the other

Tags: git, git-branch

What is the best way to have one branch for "source" files, and another branch that stores files generated by those source files? Example:

```
Dev branch:

  Tracked: 
   - test.c
   - Makefile

Deployment branch:

  Tracked:
   - test.exe
```

Then when the makefile is executed:

```
Dev branch:

  Tracked: 
   - test.c
   - Makefile

  Untracked:
   - test.exe

Deployment branch:

  Tracked:
   - test.exe
```

Then I want to commit the changes made to test.exe to the deployment branch without committing it to the development branch.

I have tried creating the "deployment" branch off of the "development" branch, deleting the development files and committing the deployment files, but I don't know how to communicate changes from the untracked test.exe in the development branch to the deployment branch. I have also tried to `git stash -u` the untracked test.exe, switch to the deployment branch and apply the stash, but git refuses to overwrite the existing test.exe. I can manually delete it, but this creates the new problem of having to delete things before unstashing them and it gets unruly for large numbers of files.

I know I could copy the files to another directory, checkout the deployment branch, move them back and commit them, but that's obviously horrible.

Comment: This, incidentally, is a nice example of why *git is not a deployment tool*. (Sorry, just my personal pet peeve).

Comment: @sleske I am beginning to agree, I'm trying to think of ways to avoid it.

Comment: @let Please share the solution you arrive to!

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not a good idea to have generated stuff version controlled. For the simple reason that the generated stuff *will* get out of sync with the code that generates it. So, the normal approach is to add anything that can be generated to your `.gitignore` file, and be done with it. (There are common exceptions to this rule, like `./configure` scripts.)

A branch that contains only generated stuff without the stuff that generates it is just as problematic, since there is no automated way to connect it to the commit that generated it.

Now, if your objective is to mark the different published versions of your program in your `git` repository, the way to go is to use tags: A tag in `git` is a reference to a commit, just like a branch is; the differences are that tags are immutable, and that tags can be signed. So, instead of checking in the build products to mark version 1.3.5, you just add a signed tag with the name `v1.3.5`. Then anyone can do `git checkout v1.3.5` and regenerate the `test.exe` at that version.

Comment: I realise this, but I wish to do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Although maybe this *can* be done, it doesn't mean that you should. cmaster's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27681403/3080396) explains this quite nicely and proposes a better solution (tags).

---

You should take a look at git's [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks): custom scripts that are fired when certain things happen.

The functionality that you're looking for could be implemented in the `post-commit` hook, located in `.git/hooks/post-commit`.

Maybe something like this (**untested**):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu # Saner mode

# Are we in the development branch?
SRC_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
[ "$SRC_BRANCH" = 'development' ] || exit 0

# Go to the other branch and commit the file
git checkout deployment
git add test.exe
git commit -f <(git log -1 --pretty=%B "$SRC_BRANCH")
```

Comment: Checking out the deployment branch will reset test.exe to its old state, overwriting any changes made in the development branch.

Comment: @let Right you are! If it's tracked in both branches then it'll be overwritten. In that case you can do a `git checkout development -- test.exe` to bring the file.

Comment: @let If the file is gitignored in the dev branch, then I'm unaware of any way of keeping the changes without some temp-file juggling :(

Comment: @let You can use a different name for `test.exe` in your deployment branch. Then you can simply add a line `cp test.exe checkedInTest.exe` to the script to copy it over. In any case, I think you should also add a call to actually build `test.exe` to the hook to avoid checking in a stale version.